# Почему всегда при нажатии на кнопку из тега "input" возвращается пустое значение?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Я сделал красивую форму входа.
Теперь пытаюсь реализовать функцию входа. НО всегда из поля ввода возвращается пустое значение. Почему? С обычным полем без css всё норм. Как это исправить?

css

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.login_form{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px #ccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

.input,
.enter{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.inputs{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.login_label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.input:focus{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cccccc;
}

.enter{
  background-color: #307fff;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: f7f7f7;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.enter:focus,
.enter:hover{
  background-color: #498fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input:focus ~ .login_label,
.input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .login_label{
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: e0e0e0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку происходит событие. А значение вероятно пытается получить ваш js-код. Проблема скорее всего в вашем обработчике отправки формы, который вам следует добавить в вопрос.

Comment: `z-index: -1;` - вероятно из-за этого... может уводит кнопку из под клика, на слой ниже... CSS приведен не полный... если где-то есть `pointer-events: none;` - это тоже может убить клик. Нужен JS / html для точного ответа.